# MySQL SELECT FROM WHERE JOIN

Tags: mysql, database, join, where-clause

I want to choose a single row from my database and join to that line.

When I am using this command it works fine:

```
SELECT p.* FROM pages AS p
JOIN products AS pro ON pro.page_id = p.id
```

but when executing the following command I am getting an error:

```
select p.* from pages as p where p.id = 21605
join products as pro on pro.page_id = p.id
```

Why is that and how can I get the result to the second command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct

```
SELECT p.* FROM pages AS p
JOIN products AS pro 
ON pro.page_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = 21605
```

**Or**

```
SELECT T.* 
FROM (SELECT p.* FROM pages AS p WHERE p.id = 21605) AS T
JOIN products AS pro 
ON pro.page_id = T.id
```

Comment: Thanks! it works, does one of them counts as a better practice? If yes, why?

Comment: The first one is better practice because it avoids a sub-query. Basic SELECT syntax is SELECT *column list* FROM *tablename* JOIN *table and On clause* WHERE *condition* GROUP BY *column list* ORDER BY *column list*  LIMIT *start offset,limit*. You omit the ones not needed.

Comment: yes @SloanThrasher is right. First one is correct. And If you got your answer please accept and upvote